# Select model where related models match criteria

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a class `Student` and class `Exam`. One student can have many exams and one exam can belong to one student. I need to select all students that have an exam in 'English', so I am attempting to do the following:

```
$english_students = Student::with('Exams')-whereHas('Exams', function($query){
    //logic to return true if the student has a related Exam with name of "English";
})
```

My problem is that I do not have a full understanding of what I can or cannot do in the closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$english_students = Student::with('Exams')-whereHas('Exams', function($query){
     $query->where("name","English");
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a where clause to the callback function:

```
$english_students = Student::with('Exams')->whereHas('Exams', function($query){

    $query->where('name', 'English');

})->get();
```

If you don't need to get exams too, then use [has](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$english_students = Student::has('exams', '=', 'English')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Student::whereHas('Exams', function($q) use($examName) {
    $q->where('name', $examName);
})
->get();
```

Also, if you don't need to load all student's exams, remove the `with()` part.

Comment: What if he wants to get exams too ?

Comment: @YouneL then he shouldn't remove the `with()` part. But OP's task sounds like he doesn't need to load all the exams for each student.

Comment: Then using `has` should be enough: `Student::has('exams', '=', 'English')->get(); `